# Delphi 7 thread synchronization hangs in debugging in Windows 8

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I had to reinstall the system. Previously I had XP pro, now I have win8.
I have installed D7(enterprise) with UpdatePack1.

The problem is as follows:

- In debugger any synchronization thread techniques cease to function after some time.

  - Invoking Synchronize with the main thread
  - even Posting message to the main thread finally hangs everything.

I will mention, that the main app thread is processing messages.

It only happens in debugger, When i run without it, everything runs smoothly ...

Thanks for any suggestions in advance ...

Comment: Before narrowing the problem to small piece of code to present I have just wanted to ask for a first thought shot ...

Comment: @GolezTrol - fwiw: I'm having the same *(intermittent)* problem but I don't have a reproducable test either. I doubt OP will be able to present one but it's one of those things where someone might just know that if you set `globberdeflop` to false you must make sure your `doedelidoe` is true.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is too much happening at once. Code through the debugger is a lot slower, since it monitor whatever is happening. So it may seem to hang, when it just takes longer.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: globberdeflop? What did you mean?

Comment: @John - Well... nothing actually. You mean that `doedelidoe` made sense to you? <g>.

Comment: This means [Gobbledygook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobbledygook) or [Gibberish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibberish) for something that is unknown.

Comment: I can't add much, other than to say that I don't tend to have the problem you describe in my highly multi-threaded apps. I never use Synchronize though - my UI will use a timer to read data from the threads. It may be that the problem always existed, and that it is just the change in OS that is showing it.

Comment: D7 is old and this could be a well known problem. Later delphi version have better support for debugging threads...

Comment: I hate all the big heads on this site that dislike a question yet they cannot answer it.

Comment: @Craig I'm not certain what you mean. I don't see how the question as asked could have been answered. I don't see any comments that are big-headed. What are you getting at?

Comment: @davidheffernan you are not one of them, you are actually very helpful, but sometimes I ask a question and then it is disliked by others who think it is a stupid question but I have no idea how to fix my problem. Its not only me some of my friends have also said they experience the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. ...

I had set compatibility mode in win8 to Xp with SP3. 
Finally I disabled that and left only to run delphi with administrative mode.

Now application works faster, and all that problems dissapeared.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't run Delphi as admin. Install it in a folder which standard user can write to. If you've already installed it to program files, add a permissive ACL to C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi. Many people install to, for example, C:\Delphi7. If you run Delphi as admin, you'll not be able to debug all the UAC bugs that your program may have.